# Module parse failed: Unexpected token when loading typescript files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module

I am creating a react application with typescript that has a root project ( empty except for backend project and client project ). The backend project has the connection code to the database, the rest service endpoints, and the Database interface and classes. The client project has all of the react gui files.

The backend project compiles and starts successfully.

```
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `npx ts-node -r dotenv/config ./src/server.ts`
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Server is listening on port 8000
```

The issue I am having is when I start the client.  It looks like it is having trouble with the Database interface and classes that I access in the backend. Here are the results when I run yarn start.

```
ERROR in ../resumemaker-backend/src/database/models/User.ts 6:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
| 
> export interface IResumeInfo {
|     resume_id: ObjectId;
|     resumeName: string;

ERROR in ../resumemaker-backend/src/utils/Utils.ts 10:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:47)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { IResume } from "../database/models/Resume";
| 
> export const addDBCategory = async (newCategory: ICategory) => {
|     await axios
|         .post(addCategory, {

webpack compiled with 9 errors
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
```

Here is `Users.ts`

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export interface IResumeInfo {
    resume_id: ObjectId;
    resumeName: string;
}

export interface IUser {
    _id: ObjectId | undefined;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    fullName: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
    createDate?: Date;
    lastAccessDate?: Date;
    resumes: IResumeInfo[];
}

export class User implements IUser {
    _id: ObjectId | undefined;
    email = "";
    password = "";
    fullName = "";
    isAdmin = false;
    createDate?: Date;
    lastAccessDate?: Date;
    resumes: IResumeInfo[];

    constructor(values: IUser) {
        this._id = values._id;
        this.email = values.email;
        this.password = values.password;
        this.fullName = values.fullName;
        this.isAdmin = values.isAdmin ?? false;
        this.createDate = values.createDate;
        this.lastAccessDate = values.lastAccessDate;
        this.resumes = values.resumes ?? ([] as IResumeInfo[]);
    }
}
```

[Here is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0j7f.png)

Here is the `package.json` for the root project

```
{
  "name": "resumebuilder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/src/server.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "resumemaker-client",
    "resumemaker-backend"
  ],
  "overrides": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn run startBackend\" \"yarn run startClient\"",
    "startClient": "cd resumemaker-client && yarn start",
    "startBackend": "cd resumemaker-backend && yarn start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    
  }
}
```

Here is the `.eslintrc.json` for the root project

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2022": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "eslint: recommended",
    "plugin: @typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "standard-with-typescript",
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["off"],
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": ["off"],
    "comma-dangle":["error", { "arrays": "always-multiline", "objects": "always-multiline", "imports": "always-multiline","exports": "always-multiline","functions": "always-multiline"}],
    "max-len": ["warn", { "code": 150 }],
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "semi": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": "warn"
  }
}
```

Here is the `tsconfig.json` for root project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "ts-node": { "transpileOnly": true},
  "lib": [ "ES2020"],
  "types": ["node"],
  "include": ["./resumemaker-backend/**/*", "./resumemaker-client/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "*.json", "dist"]
}
```

Here is the `package.json` for the backend project

```
{
  "name": "resumemaker-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Resumemaker backend",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Robert Jose",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "1.4.0",
    "babel-node": "0.0.1-security",
    "bcrypt": "5.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "16.1.4",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.0",
    "mongodb": "5.6.0",
    "openai": "3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "5.0.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "1.19.2",
    "@types/express": "4.17.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "9.0.2",
    "@types/mongodb": "4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "20.3.1",
    "@types/nodemon": "1.19.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.60.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.60.1",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "35.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "15.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "nodemon": "2.0.22",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "7.1.0",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "3.2.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "ts-postgres": "1.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Here is the `.eslintrc.json` for the backend project

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2022": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint: recommended",
    "plugin: @typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "standard-with-typescript",
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["warn"],
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": ["off"],
    "comma-dangle":["error", { "arrays": "always-multiline", "objects": "always-multiline", "imports": "always-multiline","exports": "always-multiline","functions": "always-multiline"}],
    "max-len": ["warn", { "code": 200 }],
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "semi": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": "warn"
  }
}
```

Here is the `tsconfig.json` for the backend project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  },
  "ts-node": { "transpileModule": true, "esm": true, "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"},
  "lib": [ "ES2020", "typescript"],
  "types": ["node"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "*.json", "dist"]
}
```

Here is the `package.json` for the client project

```
{
  "name": "resumemaker-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Robert Jose",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "5.0.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "3.1.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.11.16",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.136",
    "@mui/material": "5.13.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "5.12.0",
    "@mui/styles": "5.14.1",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "6.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "16.18.34",
    "@types/react": "18.2.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "axios": "1.4.0",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "material-ui-phone-number": "3.0.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "5.0.9",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "7.45.1",
    "react-router-dom": "6.11.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "resumemaker-backend": "1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.11",
    "yup": "1.2.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@hookform/devtools": "4.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.11",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.1",
    "eslint-config-react-tools": "1.1.7",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "7.1.0",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "3.2.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "typescript": "5.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the `.eslintrc.json` for the client project

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node":true,
    "es2022": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "eslint: recommended",
    "plugin: @typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "standard-with-typescript",
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["off"],
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": ["off"],
    "comma-dangle":["error", { "arrays": "always-multiline", "objects": "always-multiline", "imports": "always-multiline","exports": "always-multiline","functions": "always-multiline"}],
    "max-len": ["warn", { "code": 150 }],
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": "off",
    "semi": 0
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.{ts,tsx}"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the `tsconfig.json` for the client project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  },
  "ts-node": { "transpileModule": true, "esm": true, "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"},
  "lib": [ "ES2020", "typescript"],
  "types": ["node", "typescript"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "*.json", "dist"]
}
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Rob

I have tried changing options in .eslintrc.json and tsconfig.json, but the client never starts.

Comment: Looks like the class is loaded as ecmascript, not typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why this happens but I had the same trouble and found a workaround.

Looking at the first error:

```
> export interface IResumeInfo {
```

For some reason the compiler does not like interfaces defined in dependencies. A workaround would be to not export the interface and inline all the type info. That would fix both of your errors.

I do not fully understand why this happens myself. Maybe someone else can explain why the compiler errors out on interface (type) declarations exported from a dependency?

**edit**: Found a subjectively better alternative: You could transpile your dependency. Try creating a `next.config.js` in your client project root and add something like:

```
module.exports = {
transpilePackages: ['resumemaker-backend']
}
```

More info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#module-transpilation

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately I use the interface in other places of my application so I am not sure how I could get rid of it.  I will look into it.  I also, unfortunately, am not using nextjs.  Maybe I should look into using it :)

Comment: @RobJose Oh sorry missed that its not next! Well I had this exact same error in nextjs. I do believe transpilation of a single dependency using Babel is also possible but I don't know how exactly.